# iOS sum up the button value, calculator concept

Tags: ios, button

I'm quite new in ios development

Here I'm trying to make a basic calculator concept

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UILabel* myLabel;

int sum;
}

 -(IBAction)onePressed:(id)sender{
printf("1");

UIButton* button1 = sender;

NSString* button1Text = button1.titleLabel.text;

int value = [button1Text intValue];

// String.format("value: %d", value);
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"value: %d", value];
}

-(IBAction)twoPressed:(id)sender{
printf("2");

UIButton* button2 = sender;

NSString* button2Text = button2.titleLabel.text;

int value = [button2Text intValue];

// String.format("value: %d", value);
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"value: %d", value];
}

-(IBAction)threePressed:(id)sender{
printf("3");

UIButton* button3 = sender;

NSString* button3Text = button3.titleLabel.text;

int value = [button3Text intValue];

// String.format("value: %d", value);
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"value: %d", value];
}
```

I have make 3 buttons

when the user click one of those buttons, the value will be sum up with the previous value and the value will be shown in the label

anyone know how to do it?

thanks

Comment: Do you have a property to save the 'current' value? Have you tried summing something in the code?

Comment: there is no property to save the current value...@Wain

Comment: Your solution looks valid. What is your problem? What errors do you face?

Comment: @dasdom the problem is the value is not sum up...the label just show the value from the button...

Comment: Right. I see. Let me check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the iVar `sum` in place - you just need to total it with every button press.  As @Wain suggested, you should change to NSInteger rather than int, but either way will work.

Also, since you are using the value of the button, you only need a single action handler for all of your buttons - in IB, just connect the `touchUpInside` to a single `IBAction buttonPressed:(id)sender`

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button=(UIButton *)sender;
    sum += [button.titleLabel.text intValue];
    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"value: %d",sum];
}
```

Also, while there is nothing wrong with using an iVar, it is preferable to use properties -

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mylabel;
@property NSInteger sum;

@end

-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button=(UIButton *)sender;
    self.sum += [button.titleLabel.text intValue];
    self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"value: %d",self.sum];
}
```

Comment: The `sender.text` thing won't work I think. As far as I know you have to access the titleLabel. And you don't have to declare buttonPressed anymore.

Comment: Thanks, that was an oversight.  Fixed that.

Answer (score 4):

Add tags to you buttons. For example `twoButton.tag = 2;` or do it in the Interface Builder.

Change your code (at least) to:

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger currentValue;
@end


@implementation MyClass

- (IBAction)twoPressed:(UIButton*)sender {
    NSLog(@"twoPressed");

    self.currentValue += sender.tag;

    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"value: %d", self.currentValue];
}

@end
```

Comment: Using the label to store previousValue, while it will work, isn't the cleanest solution.  I suggest adding a property or iVar to store the running total.

Comment: @Paulw11 I've improved my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add a property to store the `current` value. As each button is pressed, add the new value to it and store that result (and show it on the label).

Try to use `NSInteger` instead of `int`.